# ¿Por qué a veces se pone "la" antes de los nombres?

Tags: gramática, artículos

En general, en español los nombres personales no requiren artículos determinados. No obstante, algunas veces he notado excepciones a esta regla. Por ejemplo, en *El Retablo de las Maravillas* de Cervantes, se menciona a "la Chirinos". Asimismo, en *La Verbena de la Paloma*, hay varias instancias de "la Susana". Tengo la impresión de que esto se restringe a las mujeres, cosa que confirma un libro mío sobre la gramática del idioma español, aunque también sostiene que en algunos países, como Chile, se usa tanto para los nombres de los hombres como para los de las mujeres. 
Además, dado que casi todos los ejemplos que he visto son de libros antigüos, también creo que podría tratarse de una forma arcaica.

¿De dónde proviene este fenómeno? ¿Cómo evolucionó? Anteriormente, ¿era más restrictivo o menos? Es decir, ¿no se utilizaba o se utilizaba para referirse a toda persona?

Comment: Me temo que no es una forma arcaica https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo_soy_la_Juani Te confirmo que en España se sigue usando tanto para hombres como para mujeres. Justamente hablaba ayer con mis amigos de "El Pepillo" ;-P

Comment: En el caso de mujeres célebres, es habitual y correcto referirse a ellas anteponiendo el artículo si se las nombra por el apellido: _La Mistral, la Kahlo, la Callas_.

Answer (score 3):

Cito para empezar el comentario sobre el [uso del artículo definido con antropónimos](https://www.rae.es/dpd/el#4). Los nombres propios de personas no requieren artículo definido, pero tampoco lo prohíben, aunque en muchas partes se considera informal o vulgar utilizarlos. En mi propia experiencia, depende casi totalmente del registro buscado y de preferencias individuales del hablante.

Es cierto que el artículo se usa más con mujeres, pero no con sus nombres de pila sino con sus apellidos. Esto, supongo, tiene que ver con la tradición de que las mujeres adultas se casen y tomen los apellidos de sus esposos, con lo cual es necesario diferenciarlos (si digo “Rodríguez” puede entenderse que me refiero al hombre, por lo cual diré “la Rodríguez”, etc.). Este uso es común todavía hoy, aun cuando las mujeres ya no se casen con tanta frecuencia y muchas veces (especialmente en el ámbito profesional) conserven sus apellidos al hacerlo.

El uso del artículo (con ambos sexos) es también común con apodos, con nombres de pila acortados y cuando la persona es famosa, pero cada caso es único. En general diría que en un diálogo se utiliza el artículo con el nombre de un tercero cuando ese tercero es bien conocido e inmediatamente identificable por ambos interlocutores. (Lo opuesto a esto es el empleo de *un tal...* o *una tal...* antes del nombre.)

Comment: Por lo menos en el pasado y en algunos lugares sí se utilizaba con nombres de pila, tales como "la Susana" y "la Casta".

Comment: Y ahora que lo leo, también "el Julián".

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco el nombre concreto la estructura que apuntas, lo que sí puedo confirmarte es que no se trata de una forma arcaica, se sigue usando en España a día de hoy.

Como muestra el título de la película de Bigas Luna, [Yo soy la Juani](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo_soy_la_Juani) (2006)

[image: Cartel de la película "Yo soy la Juani"]

Simplemente empleamos la primera acepción que da el DRAE

> [**el, la**](https://dle.rae.es/el)
>
> 1. art. deter. m. y f. Antepuesto a un sustantivo o a un sintagma nominal forma una expresión definida de referente consabido.

Es decir, lo empleamos, por ejemplo, para distinguir de entre todas las personas llamadas Pepillo (diminutivo de José), a una persona concreta - referente consabido - que vive en nuestro barrio: El Pepillo.

Answer (score 0):

La is used to refer that you are talking about someone that everybody knows. It ususally has a peyorative meaning.

Comment: I disagree with you, I've seen many examples of the use of "la" before someone's name in just colloquial or even affectionate ways. There are places where the use of "el" or "la" before names is quite common and not at all pejorative.

Comment: I think (without evidence) that in the past it was pejorative. But that currently does not have that connotation.

Comment: You can say "la" with friends, I agree is not as pejorative as is used to be. But if you are working for example I wouldn't recommend to say"la lola" referring to your boss. It is better to say "la señora Lola"

Answer (score 0):

[Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/el#4):

> 4. Uso con antropónimos. En la lengua culta, los nombres propios de persona se emplean normalmente sin artículo: *Juan es un tipo simpático; No he visto a María desde el mes pasado*. **La anteposición del artículo, en estos casos, suele ser propia del habla popular**: «Un señor mayor chiquiaba mucho a la María» (Medina Cosas [Méx. 1990]). **No obstante, hay zonas del ámbito hispánico, por ejemplo en Chile, donde esta anteposición se da también en el habla culta, habitualmente en registros coloquiales y especialmente ante nombres de mujer**: «Creo que las mujeres siguen siendo estupendas periodistas. Está la Patricia Verdugo, la Patricia Politzer» (Hoy [Chile] 8-14.12.97).